# Static Files not working on PythonAnywhere - but working on local server

Tags: python, django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I'm deploying My web app on Pythonanywhere. After deployment, static files are not shown on it.
While StaticFiles are working fine on Local Server.
Lets just say staticfiles contain an image which is shown on Local Server on Home Page but doesn't show on pythonanywhere after deploying.

What could be the issue?

I tried adding static folder in each of my app, also as a global folder. Also, configured it on settings.py correctly as well.

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    ]
```

Here's the link to my website:
http://syedhamza10.pythonanywhere.com/
It is supposed to show a logo along with The Vision Realtor

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

and then run python manage.py collectstatic

Let me know if that helps, so I can make it into an answer.

Comment: also, take a look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/